# Using SQLAlchemy, how do i update the db using json only?

Tags: sqlalchemy

some_json

```json
{ 
    "id": 1,
    "foo": "foo",
    "bar": "bar",
    "baz": "baz"
}
```

assume all the keys in `some_json` are columns

then normally when i update the database,
i'll do something like

```py
item = db.query.filter_by(id=some_json['id']).first()
if item:
    item.foo = some_json['foo']
    item.bar = some_json['bar']
    item.baz = some_json['baz']
    db.session.add(item)
    db.commit()
```

however, this can obviously be tedious if have more and more keys
is there an easier way to update the table rows just by simply passing the json?

Comment: If `isinstance(some_json, dict)` is `True` then you could try passing `some_json` as parameter values to an `insert()` statement, e.g., `db.session.execute(item.__table__.insert(), some_json)`

Comment: You should be able to do `instance = MyModel(**json_dict); db.add(instance)` if `json_dict` is a flat `dict` and its keys match column names in `MyModel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By converting `json` to dectionery, which maps the table model `table_model` in your case, you can write your code as follows:

```
a= {
    "id": 1,
    "foo": "foo",
    "bar": "bar",
    "baz": "baz"
    }
item = table_model.query.filter_by(id=some_json['id']).first()
if item:
    item=table_model(**a)
    db.session.add(item)
    db.commit()
```

Comment: If you desired more complex handling of the data you could use something like the `marshmallow-sqlalchemy` library. Marshmallow would allow you quickly load orm objects from json or a dictionary. You could also define pre/post load functions on certain ORM attributes (columns) so massage the data that comes in. E.g you could define a pre load function to encrypt a password before it's saved.
Super useful in building standard rest apis where the json passed between front and backend is usually just json'ed mappings of database orm objects.